# javascript passing an object into function

Tags: javascript, function, object

```
var o = {};
(function(x){x=null})(o);       //o is NOT null after this statement
(function(x){x.foo = "foo"; x.bar = "bar";})(o)   //o has properties foo and bar after this statement
```

---

what is going on when passing object o into the function? the first function makes it seem o did not get passed; the second function makes it seem that o get passed

Comment: In the first function you're assigning null to the variable `x`, not to `o`. If you want to assign it to `o` you have to pass it by reference.

Answer (score 5):

Line 1: An object is created. A reference to it is passed to `o`.

Line 2: A function is called. A reference to the object is passed as an argument. The reference (in `x`) is then overwritten with `null` (without touching the object itself or the reference to it still assigned to `o`).

Line 3: A function is called. A reference to the object is passed as an argument. A `foo` and `bar` property are added to the object and assigned values.

Comment: I was just thinking is there any way to remove object from the closure without return...

Answer (score 4):

```
(function(x){
  x=null
})(o);
```

`x` "points" to `o`, but you just assigned `x` to point to another thing, `null` thereby not changing `o`.

```
(function(x){
  x.foo = "foo"; 
  x.bar = "bar";
})(o);
```

In this code, you are altering the properties (adding `foo` and `bar`) of whatever `x` is pointing at, which would be `o`. This alterations will reflect to `o`.